# I am getting this error while calling an API - "Thread 1: EXC_BAD _INSTRUCTION(code = EXC_1386_INVOP,subcode = 0*0)"

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

Consider:

[image]

I am getting this error while calling the API:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD _INSTRUCTION(code = EXC_1386_INVOP,subcode = 0*0)

The main thing is getting the error in the alamofire.swift file.

Comment: Ask yourself: How would anybody be able to analyze what's going with this information? You haven't posted any code and haven't told us where in that code the problem occurs (the debugger tells you). There's also no context info. Please **edit your question** and provide more info. **Do not add these informations in a comment! Edit your question!**

Comment: Alright, the necessary info is in the image… which I didn't even notice. My bad.

Comment: The image is a bit too small to see, are you able to copy the important information out? Might make it more searchable too.

Comment: What API are you calling? [NSMutableURLRequest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutableurlrequest)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look closely, your error says:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value

Which means, that a variable that wasn't supposed do be `nil`, is `nil`.

In this code `NSURL(URL: URLString.URLString)` returns `nil`.

Check again what URL are you passing as parameter.